# List of Symbols from Google Chart Api chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small?

Tags: api, charts, google-api, symbols

Is there any list of all possible Google Chart Api chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small Symbols??

Example:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=ski|bb|My_Point_Name|eeeeee|000000
```

i do mean the chld=ski parameter. Are there any othe symbols possible?

Answer (score 0):

found them: (needs long to load, so i had never seen them before)
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#icon_list